# Neither-nor oneline REGEXP

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Is it possible to write a regexp rule in "one line" that says: neither A nor B.

For example:

`String must contain NEITHER "foo" NOR "bar".`

Why one line? Because the filtering tool I am using accepts only one line ... I have tried things like `(.*foo.*){0}(.*bar.*){0}` without enough luck.

Answer (score 9):

```
^(?!.*(foo|bar)).*$
```

Comment: @Simon negative look-ahead: `(?!REGEX_1)REGEX_2` will fail if `REGEX_1` matches, but won't consume any characters so that matching of `REGEX_2` will start at the same position. There is positive look-ahead `(?=REGEX_1)REGEX_2` and their look-behind counter parts. Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html